# How do I get values from the link table in DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

In my app I have 2 table, books and tags, and the link table book_tags. The link table also contains the number of times the book was tagged with this particular tag. I can add a tag by doing

```
$book->add_tag($tag, { tag_count => 10 });
```

However when I retrieve the tags for a book

```
@tags = $book->tags();
```

it does not seem to return the values from the link table.

Is there a way to get the values from the link table without doing it by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a join table named `book_tags`, you will have to create a `many_to_many` relationship from the `books` table to the `has_many` relation of the `books` table itself. The `has_many` relation should retrieve the `id`s of the tags associated with the book from the table `book_tags`. You may have to add relationships similar to:

In `Your::App::Schema::Result::Book`:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many( book_tags => 'Your::App::Schema::Result::BookTag', 'book_id' );

__PACKAGE__->many_to_many( tags => 'book_tags', 'tag' );
```

In `Your::App::Schema::Result::BookTag`:

```
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to( tag => 'Your::App::Schema::Result::Tag', 'tag_id' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I had trouble finding an example of using a link table with this ORM.  Was able to apply this successfully to my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can `proxy` properties through relationships like this:

```
Schema::Tag->has_many('book_tags' => 'Schema::BookTag',  
  undef, {  
    proxy => [ 'tag_count' ],  
  }  
);
```

Then you can access 'tag_count' like this:

```
my $tag_rs = $book->tags;
for( my $tag = $tag_rs->next ){
  print $tag->tag_count;
}
```

You can find more at the [relationship docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Relationship/Base.pm#add_relationship).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I have already done this part, and it works.

My tables look like this:

BOOK:

```
book_id book_title [other fields]
```

TAG:

```
tag_id tag_name [other fields]
```

BOOK_TAG:

```
book_id tag_id tag_count
```

So I have a many-to-many relationship between tags and books with an additional attribute, tag_count, which is stored in the link table.

I can add a tag to a book by doing

```
$book->add_to_tags($tag, { tag_count => 10 } );
```

which populates the tag_count field in the BOOK_TAG table.

But when I do

```
$book->tags();
```

it does not automatically retrieve tag_count field from BOOK_TAG. I can write

```
$tag = $schema->resultset('BookTag')->find( { book_id=>$book->book_id, tag=>$tag->tag_id });
$tag_count = $tag->tag_count();
```

I'm trying to see if there is an easier way to get the extra attribute from the link table.